# Detecting an error in the computation of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I apologize if the error is easily spotted. But, here it is:

If we are computing $$\int^1_0{\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}}dy$$ and use the substitution $y\rightarrow x \tan(\theta)$ to get 
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{x^2-x^2\tan^2(\theta)}{(x^2+x^2\tan^2(\theta))^2}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\tan^2(\theta)}{(1+\tan^2(\theta))^2}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$$ $$=\frac{1}{x}\int^{\pi/4}_0 \cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{2x}$$

This is wrong since there is the antiderivative $\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we get $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. I cannot find the error though.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=x \tan{\theta}$, the boundaries of the integrals must be $0$ and $\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}$:
$$0 = x \tan{\theta} \\ \theta = 0$$
and
$$1 = x \tan{\theta} \\ \theta = \arctan{\frac{1}{x}}$$

So, your last line would be:
$$
\frac {1}{x} \int_{0}^{\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}} {\cos{2\theta}} \space d\theta = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$

Hope this helps.

Update: len spotted out your other mistake. In the first line of your equation, the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is factored out but in the second line, one of the $x$s vanish mysteriously. This is because $d y = x \sec^2{\theta} \space d\theta$, not $sec^2{\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

$y = x\tan\theta$

$dy$ should be $x\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$

And $1/x$ should be $\tan\theta$ while substitution

Therefore, your first substitution step is wrong